# Radio button field no setting default checked

Tags: field

I have two radio buttons on a field. I check one of the options as default so it's checked automatically, but when I visit the entry it's on, both of them are unchecked.

I've tried deleting and remaking and it still doesn't select default.

Has anyone had this issue?

Comment: What version of Craft are you running?

Comment: Hi, @BradBell. I'm using Craft Pro 3.1.26

Comment: Just updated to 3.22 and issue still present.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this locally on a fresh Craft 3.2.2 install.  If you want to send a database backup, your composer.json and composer.lock files over to support@craftcms.com and give us some steps to reproduce, we can look into it further.

Comment: I'm having this issue now. In the past it always seems to select the default if it's a new entry(like I've [read](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/2445) is the expected behaviour) but this time it's never selecting it. I've tried moving the fields to different sections, deleting all the entries and I recently used the project.yaml on a fresh install but that didn't help either. Craft version is "Craft Solo 3.2.10".

Answer (score 1):

I've got a radio button field on Commerce products that is also not visibly showing as checked. Inspecting shows the correct input is actually showing checked="". Manually adjusting this to checked="checked" makes the radio button re-appear. Doesn't help us in the meantime, but perhaps it's as simple as that to fix the issue? Safari and Firefox on Mac.